# Java object serialization does not serialize fields value in WCF REST service

Tags: java, xml, wcf, serialization

I have WCF REST service and that service is consumed from Java client. I serialized java object as XML and sent request as POST. Object has serialized but all filed value is null.

Class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
```

@XmlRootElement(name = "Passenger",namespace="www.test.com/api/v1.0")
public class Passenger implements Serializable{

```
@XmlElement(name = "Id")
private int Id;

@XmlElement(name = "Name")
private String Name;

@XmlElement(name = "Location")
private String Location ;

@XmlElement(name = "Address")
private String Address;

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.Id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.Location = location;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.Address = address;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:Passenger xmlns:ns2="www.test.com/api/v1.0">
<Address>234 Queens</Address>
<Id>1300</Id>
<Location>New York</Location>
<Name>John Doe</Name>
</ns2:Passenger>
```

WCF DataContract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "www.test.com/api/v1.0")]
public class Passenger
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

Operation
public Passenger UpdatePassenger(Passenger passenger)
    {
        var passengers = CreatePassenger();

        var person = passengers.Where(p => p.Id == passenger.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        return person;
    }
```

I am receiving passenger object but all field values are null.

Another observation: If i remove namespace from java class, then all fields value are serialized. But i need to put namespace in both WCF and Java code.

Any hints/idea or sample code is appreciable.

Comment: Make sure that the fields were actually initialized, and try setting ```required=true``` as an argument to ```@XmlElement``` annotations. Also, Implementing Serializable should not accomplish anything as it is used for serialization of objects in regards to a [format standardized by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/serialization/protocol.html) (independent of XML). The link is for Java SE 11, although I don't believe the specifications have changed since JDK 1.2